# How to set vim theme in Vagrant?

Tags: vimrc, colorscheme

I installed Vagrant within Windows, box is ubuntu server 14.04.

My vim script:

```
set t_Co=256
colorscheme solarized
" colorscheme molokai
```

But it doesn't works, and I got no solutions with Google.

Who can tell me how to do?

Comment: So did you install solarized on the VM?

Comment: yes, Bundle 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized'

Comment: If you set the colorscheme manually does it work? aka `:set colorscheme solarized`? If not, then there was a problem with installation.

Comment: `:colorscheme solarized` is works, but background color doesn't change.

Comment: Is your terminal _really_ 256 colors? What is the output of `echo $TERM`?

Comment: `xterm-256color`

Comment: Try manually putting the solarised.vim color scheme into the vim color folder.